# how to create character code from number code in php using json

Tags: php, arrays, json, unicode, character-encoding

This is my code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$form_num = $_GET['num'];

echo '<form name="creative" action = "'.htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?num='.$form_num.'" method="POST" >';

echo '<table>';

for ( $i=0; $i < $form_num ; $i++ ) {

    echo "<tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type='text' name='title$i' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Description: </td><td><input type='text' name='desc$i' /></td></tr>";


    echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}

echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update' /></td>
        <td><input type='reset' value='Reset' /></td></tr>";

echo '</table>';

echo '</form>';

if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {

    require 'ad.php';

    $ad = new adnetwork( $hostname, $user, $password, $database );

    echo 'Status is active and set notifications are : <br /><br />';

    for ($i=0; $i< $form_num; $i++) {

        $params[] = array(
            'title' => $ad->utf8_to_unicode(html_entity_decode($_REQUEST["title$i"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")),
            'description' => $ad->utf8_to_unicode(html_entity_decode($_REQUEST["desc$i"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")),    

    }

    file_put_contents( dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . 'get_text_in_test.json', json_encode( $params ) );     
}

?>
```

Here when i submitted form using a function for parse input number code to character code is:

```
public function utf8_to_unicode( $str ) {

            $unicode = array();        
            $values = array();
            $lookingFor = 1;

            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen( $str ); $i++ ) {
                $thisValue = ord( $str[ $i ] );
                if ( $thisValue < ord('A') ) {
                // exclude 0-9
                    if ($thisValue >= ord('0') && $thisValue <= ord('9')) {
                    // number
                    $unicode[] = chr($thisValue);
                    }
                    else {
                        $unicode[] = ''.chr($thisValue);
                    }           
                } else {
                    if ( $thisValue < 128) 
                        $unicode[] = $str[ $i ];
                    else {
                        if ( count( $values ) == 0 ) $lookingFor = ( $thisValue < 224 ) ? 2 : 3;                
                            $values[] = $thisValue;                
                                if ( count( $values ) == $lookingFor ) {
                                    $number = ( $lookingFor == 3 ) ?
                                    ( ( $values[0] % 16 ) * 4096 ) + ( ( $values[1] % 64 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[2] % 64 ):
                                    ( ( $values[0] % 32 ) * 64 ) + ( $values[1] % 64 );

                                    $number = dechex($number);
                                    $unicode[] = (strlen($number)==3)?"\u0".$number:"\u".$number;
                                    $values = array();
                                    $lookingFor = 1;
                                } // if
                        } // if
                    }
            } // for

            return implode("",$unicode);

        }
```

when i pass string like this **❤★♫Cute Pics** it should give me character code of these symbols, for achieve this first i decode my input character and then throw decoded string in function which gave me result like this: **\u2764\u2605\u266b Cute Pics**, but when i am json_encode this string which is bounded in array is:

```
$params[] = array(
                'title' => $ad->utf8_to_unicode(html_entity_decode($_REQUEST["title$i"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")),
                'description' => $ad->utf8_to_unicode(html_entity_decode($_REQUEST["desc$i"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")),    

        }

echo json_encode($params);
```

It put an extra slash in front of character code which is not interpreted by my android phone. As these characters code escaped by slashes, but **json** again put slashes which is not readable by android phone. Also, i am not using database, so i out these json in a json formatted file, later i grab all data from json file using php function **file_get_content** and then using it. Please help me on this problem.

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Are you trying to rewrite `json_encode()` or something?

Comment: Was going to ask the same question - why are you doing this? Why not just pass the UTF characters into json_encode and let it encode them?

Comment: @Danack: if i directly json encode the input, then it shows only number code in json

Comment: if i passed html_entity_decode($_REQUEST["title$i"], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")) argument, then it shows json with single slashe, but not working on mobile, is there any way to create directly a character code of these symbols?

Comment: "then it shows json with single slashe, but not working on mobile" How is it not working? What do you see happen, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are either double decoding the strings you are being passed.

Running this code:

```
for ($i=0; $i< 2; $i++) {
    $params[] = array(
        'title' => "❤★♫Cute Pics",
        'description' => "This is some description",
    );
}

echo json_encode($params);
```

Outputs:

```
[{"title":"\u2764\u2605\u266bCute Pics","description":"This is some description"},{"title":"\u2764\u2605\u266bCute Pics","description":"This is some description"}]
```

Which is valid JSON, which should be interpreted on the phone just fine (unless it doesn't support UTF8).

I think you should just delete the call to `html_entity_decode` unless you're sure that you're receiving encoded strings (which you almost certainly aren't because the web server decodes them for you), and also remove utf8_to_unicode because `json_encode` goes straight from UTF8 to properly encoded JSON - you don't have to do it yourself.

> then it shows json with single slashe, but not working on mobile

Then that would be a problem with the how the mobile is decoding the JSON, which you would need to address there.

Comment: mobile accepts character codes, before some time i had test this scenario directly with mobile, json_encode parse all symbols in character code and it shows on mobile.But there is a problem with current scenario, i am receiving these symbols from user input

Comment: When i am trying to use directly json_encode, it convert symbols to number code as:  ❤★♫ => &#10084;&#9733;&#9835

Comment: No - json_encode won't do that, unless you're using a non-standard json_encode function. The one included with PHP encodes it correctly: http://3v4l.org/2QhXl#v445 Those are HTML encoded entities that you're seeing. Either the form is being passed to your script incorrectly, or something else in your code is calling htmlentities on those variables.

Comment: i provide you complete source code,and if i pass direct utf code and convert it using json encode then it shows character code but not render on android phone, on other hand if i specify json manually and send on android phone then it render character code!! strange but not technical reasonable

Comment: You may have two separate problems which is making it hard to debug. I suggest just displaying something that you know to be valid JSON on the handset to try and separate the problem you may be having on the handset from the problem you may be having with encoding your data.